# Automatically import daily .txt file into Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have an excel file that I pull data into from a .txt file that is generated every day on a network drive, and I'm currently doing this manually every morning.  I would like to automate this process so after midnight when the new .txt file is created Excel will automatically go get the new file and replace the data from the previous days.

The report filenames look like this:
    P:_warehouse\score-cards\0610-ScoreCards.txt
    P:_warehouse\score-cards\0611-ScoreCards.txt
    P:_warehouse\score-cards\0612-ScoreCards.txt
    P:_warehouse\score-cards\0613-ScoreCards.txt

While I'm fairly deft at the front-end of things with Excel, I'm pretty green on the coding side which I know this will require, so any basic help is appreciated.  Thanks!

Comment: Are you planning on leaving your Excel running overnight  in order to do this at said time, or would it be acceptable to run the script automatically when you open the excel file in the morning?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Unfortunately, we are not a code-writing service. Instead of simply asking for code to perform a particular task, please show us what you've tried so far (including any code you currently have) and where you're stuck so that we can help you with your specific problem. Questions that only ask for code are too broad and are likely to be [put on hold or closed](http://stackoverflow.com/help/closed-questions).

Comment: There are different ways of doing this. You can write a macro so that all you'll need to do is fire up Excel and run the macro to pull in the latest data. You can also write a stand-alone VBScript that can completely automate Excel, including launching it and pulling in the data.

Comment: @SteveTaylor Excel will be running 24/7 with the main file open.  That way I would be able to see the newest data on my phone when I'm away from my desk/work.

Comment: That really sounds like it's out of excel's scope and might be better suited as a database connection. That said, if you want to stick with excel, I'd suggest a scheduled task that opens and executes it, then saves the updated file to a location you can access remotely.

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement with user data from a system that is pulled out periodically.

The way I approach this (far from being the only way of course) is to create TWO copies of the new text files. One dated for historical record, the other simply titled something like:

```
P:_warehouse\score-cards\Latest-ScoreCards.txt
```

I then use Microsoft's Excel PowerQuery addin (massively useful), to always pull in the latest data. PowerQuery uses a point and click approach to doing extract and transformation processes from many different types of data source. So you can tidy up, filter and enrich the data at the same time as you import it if you need to.

The import could be automated but as you only have to press the Refresh button and because I like to see the old data briefly before updating, I've left it manual.

Comment: This was actually one workaround I had considered, but I'm going to have to get with IT about creating the second .txt file as that's out of my jurisdiction.